# Estimating special values of the Riemann zeta function on the critical line

Tags: number-theory, approximation

If $p,q$ are primes, is it necessarily true that
$$\left|\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{p}{q}\right)\right| > (p+q)^{–(p+q)} ?$$ (Here $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.)

Comment: Where have you find it?